# Install FFMPEG on RHEL/CentOS

Tags: centos, rhel, ffmpeg

I've been searching for hours now and trying various methods of installing FFMPEG on my CentOS server. This is what I have currently installed on my Ubuntu desktop:

```
FFmpeg version 0.6.2-4:0.6.2-1ubuntu1.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the Libav developers
  built on Sep 16 2011 17:00:39 with gcc 4.5.2
  configuration: --extra-version=4:0.6.2-1ubuntu1.1 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-vaapi --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-shared --disable-static
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  libavutil   configuration: --extra-version=4:0.6.2-1ubuntu2+medibuntu1 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libdirac --enable-libgsm --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-version3 --enable-vaapi --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libfaac --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libfaad --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaad --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-libdc1394 --enable-shared --disable-static
  libavcodec  configuration: --extra-version=4:0.6.2-1ubuntu2+medibuntu1 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libdirac --enable-libgsm --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-version3 --enable-vaapi --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libfaac --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libfaad --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaad --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-libdc1394 --enable-shared --disable-static
  libswscale  configuration: --extra-version=4:0.6.2-1ubuntu2+medibuntu1 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libdirac --enable-libgsm --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-version3 --enable-vaapi --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libfaac --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libfaad --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaad --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-libdc1394 --enable-shared --disable-static
  libpostproc configuration: --extra-version=4:0.6.2-1ubuntu2+medibuntu1 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libdirac --enable-libgsm --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-version3 --enable-vaapi --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libfaac --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libfaad --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaad --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-libdc1394 --enable-shared --disable-static
  libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1
  libavcodec    52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
  libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
  libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
  libavfilter    1.19. 0 /  1.19. 0
  libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffmpeg'
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...
```

I'm particularly interested in `--enable-librtmp`, as I need to use FFMPEG to stream to a RTMP server.

I've followed numerous tutorials, (one in particular had me install a DAG repository which no longer exists x|) but aren't really having too much luck. How can I install it on my server with the functionality I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install it from source:

```
svn checkout svn://svn.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg/trunk ffmpeg
cd ffmpeg
./configure
make
```

Then as root:

```
make install
```

Check the dependency list of ffmpeg, *before* you carry out the above steps. Make sure you have all the necessary packages. Alternatively, the dependencies can also be installed from source. For example, to compile faac and faad, download and extract faac and faad from audiocoding.com.

As above, run

```
./configure
make
su -c 'make install'
```

Install LAME if you want mp3 support.

Download codecs:

```
git clone git://git.videolan.org/x264.git
cd x264
./configure
make
```

when "configuring ffmpeg", instead of just typing "./configure", you can specify which modules you want to enable as follows:

./configure --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-pthreads --enable-libx264 --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libmp3lame
make

Do then:

```
su -c 'make install'
```